# Action successful text is not setting up in yii2

Tags: yii2

somehow my `actionResetPassword` success message doesn't show. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public function actionChangePassword() 
{
    $user = User::loadModel(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
    $user->scenario = 'changePassword';
    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user->validatePassword($user['old_password'])) {
            $user->setPassword($user['new_password']);
            $this->saveObject($user, Yii::t('app', 'Your password was changed successfully.'), Yii::t('app', 'Something is wrong'));
            $this->goHome();
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'You have entered wrong old password');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('change-password', [
        'model' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

saveObject() function:

```
function saveObject($object = NULL, $successMessage = '', $errorMessage = '') 
{
    if ($object->save()) {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', $successMessage);
    } else {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', $errorMessage);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It redirects to my homepage, but somehow doesn't show my `Yii:t` messages. Why?

Comment: update your question and add  your saveObject  function please ..

Comment: Question updated

Comment: you have always error message or you have alway no  message ?

Comment: I don't get any message at all.

Answer (score 0):

check if in your layout (eg: views\layout\main.php)  if you have

```
use common\widgets\Alert;
....

<?= Alert::widget() ?>
```

if you don't have a widget  try use

```
var_dump( Yii::$app->getSession()->getFlash());
```

in your view

Comment: I do not have it

Comment: then could be taht  you don't see the message because  you don't have a widget (or som code) for show the alter ..  what do you use for show the alert message?